# Integration tests fail when checking function that can throw error

Tags: javascript, integration-testing

I have a function that looks as follows:

```
function foo() {
   const x = await getData();
   
   if (x && x['token']) {
        // do stuff
   } else {
      throw Error("Doesn't exist")
   }
}
```

when running my integration tests, I am getting an issue with the tests failing because it's throwing.  This is old code though and not a new change. I work on a large project and think there was a recent change in the test suite but not sure where to check first to start debugging

Comment: Either the tests have detected a regression (because the token should exist and it doesn't), or the tests need to be updated to expect the error in those cases.

Comment: Firstly that's not syntactically valid - you can't await in a non-async function. Secondly it's unclear what the test is. Please give a [mre].